# If $P$ is a projective module, then there exist a free module $F$ with $P\bigoplus F$ is free.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have to prove the above question. So, if $P$ is projective then there exist a $Q$ such that $P\bigoplus Q=F'$ where $F'$ is free. I was thinking that may be we should take $F(Q)-$ free module generated by $Q$ and show that $P\bigoplus F(Q)=F'$. But how to do it, I don't know. Can anybody help?

Thank you

Comment: You must be suppressing some assumptions. The module has to have a finite free resolution for this to be true.

Comment: @Ben What do you mean by suppressing?

Comment: I accidentally hit enter before I finished the sentence.

Comment: @Ben I don't think I am missing any assumptions because it is an exercise question given in a standard book

Comment: Oh, so $F$ need not be finitely generated? Then this is the so-called Eilenberg swindle.

Comment: Yes, $F$ can be any free module

Comment: Well, then, here is a hint: consider $F'=Q\oplus P\oplus Q\oplus P\oplus \dots$

Comment: @Ben Thank you very much, I got it.

Comment: Yes it is similar to Eilenberg swindle.